# Would such a "big list" on known bounds for distances between $2^S-3^N$ be appropriate for MO?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

After new questions and/or activities on older questions on "bounds for distances  $2^S-3^N$"  appeared in MO I thought whether a [BigList] or [CommunityWiki] on known such bounds (their references in literature and possibly their analytical derivations) would be helpful/meaningful/appropriate for MO.

I had a couple of weeks ago started the introduction for such a BigList, and, because it is much longer than to be useful for the body of this question, I give here only a link to the draft in the [sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4668/1714)     (Note, the given sandbox-link shall be operatable only a couple of weeks)

It contains, for motivation, two "classical" known bounds (G. Rhin and J. W. Ellison).
Moreover, I added one conjectural bound of mine, with a different basic characteristic of the formula but very nice fitting for $N$ up to 1 million digits.
Perhaps this whole draft should thus be separated into 3 "answers" from the very start.

*Remark after rereading my draft with this current question in mind: the intro/motivation should surely be rewritten/reorganized at all.*

What do you think about starting such a [big-list]?

Comment: A good big-list question should prompt many and diverse answers, and I don't think this question does that.